# mongodb update with $set and $upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to add a new document if not exists and update attributes if exists. as well as while updating a document, create attributes if not exists.

I tried the below way. but it works only updates.

```
      Fbuser= {};
      Fbuser.name = response.name;
      Fbuser.status = "active";
      Fbuser.profile_image = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture?width=150&height=150";

      db.Users.update({"email":response.email},{$set:Fbuser},{upsert:true})
```

Comment: Can you show us some test documents and the expected output? Is `Fbuser` an object or a string variable?

Comment: @chridam Fbuser is an object `{"email":"ab@cd.com"}`

Answer (score 4):

$set needs always a value:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Try this:

```
db.Users.update({"email":response.email},{$set:{Fbuser: null}}, {upsert:true})
```

Comment: Perhaps `Fbuser` is an object like `Fbuser = { name: 'test' }`?

Comment: In that case, it would work, so he wouldn't be posting a question lol

Comment: @MartinE.Zulliger Please checkout my edited question.

Comment: Hi! I copy and paste your code into mongo and it just works, even if it's an update or a new document, in both cases it works just right.